# ui routing without urlRouterProvider.otherwise

Tags: angularjs, go, routes, angular-ui-router, gorilla

Routing doesn't occur if I don't include $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); in the config.

my go app engine setting with gorilla is

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc(/admin, handleAdmin)
```

and angularjs config is;

```
angular.module('admin')
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/admin/index.html',
        controller: 'AdminController as admin'
      });
  //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
})
```

when I don't call $urlRouterProvider.othwerwise line, and I open http://localhost:8080/admin I expect to see admin/index.html, but I don't. I see it only if I navigate to http://localhost:8080/admin#/ manually.
But if I add $urlRouterProvider.othwerwise option and go to http://localhost:8080/admin it redirects automatically to http://localhost:8080/admin#/
I don't think this is usual way to do it because I may want "otherwise" to route to a custom 404 page. What point do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

By default, Angular adds the **hashPrefix** in front of urls. So when you navigate to `http://localhost:8080/admin` , You don't see index.html since you have not yet visited the url as defined in the angular's ui-router. You will have to navigate to `http://localhost:8080/admin/#/` to actuall be in the `/` state of your application.

It is the same reason that your app doesn't work without the `.otherwise()`, since then it automatically redirects you to the `/` state later.

For a possible fix:

Inside your `.config` function:

```
// This is in your app module config.
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

And in your `index.html`:

```
// This is in your index.html head.
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Ok I tried this and it works (despite many errors in the console window) but I want the same functionality when I go to http://localhost where another module is responsible and I use ngNewRouter, it redirects automatically to http://localhost:8080/#/ while html5 is not enabled.

Comment: Your application must have a main module in which all the other modules are injected, attach it to that module's config function to get it to function in your whole of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with not having a declared `otherwise`.

The problem lays on your route. You're specifying the url to be `'/'`, that means the state **home** is accessible only through **http://localhost:8080/admin/** and NOT through **http://localhost:8080/admin**

What the `otherwise` does is. When you access the url **http://localhost:8080/admin** the router try to find a state that matches the url, but don't find it. So it redirects to **http://localhost:8080/admin/** which matches with your **home** state.